# Podcast app that can create playlists

Tags: music, music-player, podcast

I asked before about a podcast app that is able to share it's episodes with the default music player. Does anyone know of a podcast app that takes it a step further and generates playlists for each podcast (playlists that would be visible in the default music player or any music player capable of handling m3u's).

Answer (score 0):

So I've discovered that beyond pod will do this. It has an autoplaylist function that will allow you to build smart playlists. There is an option in the settings that will share this playlist with other apps (basically it generates and M3u and updates it as it downloads podcasts).

This works OK. I'd love if there was an app that could generate a per-podcast playlist, but for the time being having a single playlist with all my podcasts is better than having to search for them within my entire music catalog.